# IBM System x3550 M2 fails to complete POST

Tags: ibm

We've some IBM System x3550 M2 machines and one of them fails to start with checkpoint code `06` in the Lightpath information display.

There's no video, no beeps, nothing happens. The system just start it's fans and leds, nothing more.

I've looked through technical documents and this kind of information in completely missing from technical manuals.

The only information I got from the manuals are:

```
Checkpoint code display: This display provides a checkpoint code that indicates 
the point at which the system stopped during the boot block and POST. A checkpoint 
code is either a byte or a word value that is produced by UEFI. The display does 
not provide error codes or suggest components to be replaced.
```

Which is insufficient to troubleshoot the problem.

Comment: That sounds like the reason you have a hardware support contract. But isn't the idea of light path that in case of hardware error when you remove the cover a led on the main board lights up in the problem area?

Comment: Yep, but nothing shows up and the Checkpoint code stays at 06. We are out of hardware support, so there's no way to ask IBM to come here :(